# REST giving 404

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, web.xml, url-pattern

I have written a REST webservice using jersey in a project where it works fine(eclipse). Now I am trying to move that webservice into an already existing project but there its failing with 404 status. 
The web.xml of the project where it was working is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
       <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now with this configuration and "jerseyhelloworldtest" being name of my .war file, I am able to access the webservice using URL http://localhost:8080/jerseyhelloworldtest/rest/files/name
But when I move the same webservice to another project and change the jerseyhelloworldtest with that project's .war file name its not working there. The web.xml of the project is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Softwarepartwebservice</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
   <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
         <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
  <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Part Creator</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
 </web-app>
```

Now here I am trying to access the same webservice by using URL http://localhost:8080/Softwarepartwebservice/rest/files/name but its giving 404.
Need help with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry it was a very silly mistake made by me which I never noticed. On changing the project I had to update the package entry in

```
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

to my new package where service class was put. com.javatpoint.rest was the package from old project which I changed to new one. Changing that made it work. Writing here in case this might help someone facing the same issue.